# How do I install/emulate object storage locally?

Tags: filesystems, object-storage, file-storage

There are 3 storage types I know:

- File Storage (e.g. regular NTFS file system)
- Block Storage (e.g. SQL server installed locally)
- Object Storage

As far as I know, Object Storage is only provided by cloud providers like Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage and Azure Blob Storage.

Is there a way I can install object storage locally?

Comment: This question really isn't about any of the cloud providers you tagged. Plus... it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can 'install object storage' locally.

While you can't run S3 or GCS (Google Cloud Storage) or Azure Blob Storage locally, what you *can* run are object storage solutions that are compatible with S3, GCS and/or Azure Blob Storage.

They do so by adhering to the S3/GCS/Azure Blob Storage interfaces, supporting the same operations and API endpoints. As a side note, S3 and GCP are actually quite interoperable as with a few tweaks, the [GCS XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability#xml_api) should technically work with any tool that supports S3.

A couple of solutions exist, including but not limited to (in alphabetical order):

- [Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio) (by Microsoft) for Azure Blob Storage
- [Ceph](https://ceph.io/en/discover/technology/#object) (third party) for S3, GCP (using the XML API)
- [GCP Storage Emulator](https://github.com/oittaa/gcp-storage-emulator) (third party) for GCP, *possibly* S3
- [MinIO](https://min.io/) (third party) for S3, GCP (using the XML API)

Comment: How do I install it locally? I don't want to use any of the cloud providers in any way.

Comment: Use MinIo via a Docker container for example.